# How to fix Warning: Application ID is not set?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I always get the error 'Application ID is not set' in my log files while I have set this ID like they say in this [example](https://github.com/alexa/skill-sample-nodejs-howto):

```
const APP_ID = 'amzn1.ask.skill.xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx';
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Problem is that this example is deprecated.

At the botton of your `index.js` you will find this code:

```
exports.handler = (event, context) => {
    const alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context);
    alexa.APP_ID = APP_ID;
    // To enable string internationalization (i18n) features, set a resources object.
    alexa.resources = languageStrings;
    alexa.registerHandlers(handlers);
    alexa.execute();
};
```

And `alexa.APP_ID = APP_ID;` is wrong. They changed it to `alexa.appId`.

So if you change your line to:

```
alexa.appId = APP_ID;
```

You will not get this error message anymore. Here is the [documentation](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-nodejs).

Comment: Looks like this is deprecated again... `ReferenceError: APP_ID is not defined`

Comment: @DmitryGrinko alexa.APP_ID seems to be deprecated if you have a closer look into the current code ;)

Comment: Yes. But I've commented your comment. I'm agree with this answer